# Using GIT with projects that have directories in multiple locations

Tags: git, codeigniter, frameworks

I'm in the middle of trying to move a PHP/MySQL web app (built on CodeIgniter 2.01 framework) to a GIT repository. The problem is for added security I've implemented the best practice of separating the application part (application & system folders) and the web files (index.php, images, css, js, etc. folders). The web files are located in /var/www and the application stuff is located in /data/company/apps/myapp.

Since I would like to keep this added security, how do I migrate a project that has multiple locations like this into GIT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the structure of your Git repository and the structure of the *deployed* files need to match:

- either you add an extra step (`post-receive` hook for instance) copying the files from your Git repo to the right system paths (you separate SCM -- Source Control management -- from RM -- Release Management),
- or you link directly your two system paths to the two relevant directories within your Git repo.

I added in the comments:

> if you reorganize your repo's content in order to have to directories with the relevant content, you can make two `git archive` for each directory, and extract them in the right places.

To which the [OP crashintoty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/465531/crashintoty) replied:

> I found the solution with the following commands in `post-update`:

```
git archive --format=tar master:guts/  | \
  tar -C /data/company/apps/myapp -x 
git archive --format=tar master:skin/ | tar -C /var/www -x
```

Comment: hmmm... how would the hook suggestion work with multiple developers who live test their changes on their own sandbox/dev server (i.e., they're running LAMP on their own server, live testing their commits/local repo before pushing it to the group's sandbox/dev server)??

Comment: @crashintoty: they would push to a *local* bare repo with a local version of the post-receive hook (adapted to a local deployment in their own server). If the local live test passes, then they push to the group's sandbox/dev server.

Comment: Ha! That's right, they can use hooks too! I should of known that (my brain must be really tired). Thanks @VonC!

Comment: And just out of curiosity, the link solution proposed for the original question would essentially have the repo folder with, for example, a folder called "guts" (symbolic link to /data/company/apps/myapp) and a folder called "skin" (symbolic link to /var/www) in them?

Comment: @crashintoty: yes, you can have the two set of files in their dedicated Git directories, whatever the name of those directories are. The important part is that the directories *content* get eventually copied or referenced by the right system paths (`/data/...` or `/var/www`)

Comment: Currently my repo only manages the application stuff ("guts") and my `post-update` hook file is setup to copy the code to the right system path upon a git push:  

`#!/bin/sh
git archive --format=tar HEAD | (cd /data/company/apps/myapp && tar xf -)`  

Now that I'm adding the web files ("skin") to the repo, what should my `post-update` be changed to?

Comment: @crashintoty: if you reorganize your repo's content in order to have to directories with the relevant content, you can make two `git archive` for each directory, and extract them in the right places.

Comment: Thank you very very very much @VonC!! I found the solution with the following commands in `post-update`: `git archive --format=tar master:guts/ | tar -C /data/company/apps/myapp -x` and `git archive --format=tar master:skin/ | tar -C /var/www -x`

Comment: @crashintoty: excellent :) I have included your solution in my answer.